# Setting model to view outside of the mainwindow class

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to set the model (setModel) of a ui view outside of the mainwindow class, inside the main window its simple, something like `ui->tableView->setModel(new model)` but outside of the mainwindow I don't have access to ui.

How do I get access to the ui outside of the mainwindow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If you have access to the main window from another class, you can add method `view` to the main window which will return a pointer to the view.

```
void ClassA::methodB()
{
   m_mainWindow->view()->setModel(new Model());
}
```

2.Otherwise you can pass a pointer to the view as an argument to another class constructor:

```
ClassA* a = new ClassA(ui->tableView);
```

3.or create a method in `ClassA` to assign the view:

```
void ClassA::setView(QAbstractItemView* view)
{
     view->setModel(new Model);
}

ClassA* a = new ClassA();
a->setView(ui->tableView);
```

Comment: Hey thanks man :) I actually figured something out whilst waiting for a reply, I created a method that returned ui so I can create a new instance of mainwindow in any calss and use the ui. returned from the method. All of these are great though, I like the first option.